# SQLite create table from table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to create a copy of the table in `SQLite`. Result table should have only one difference. One of the rows called 'Desired_row' must have different type(`int` -> `bigint`).

If I knew full source table structure I could just create a new table with identical fields.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTableCopy(... , )
```

As I have different versions of the table, I do not exactly know its full structure to create a new one with hardcoded columns. I need something which will do something like this `CREATE TABLE Destination AS SELECT * FROM Source`, but will not create `Desired_row` in the Destination table.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with

```
SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='mytable'
```

you can get the the structure. This you can modify and create your new table. And finally you can

```
INSERT INTO 'MyTableCopy' (*) SELECT * FROM 'mytable'
```

Comment: As I see there is not way to create a script with this solution. I can modify received sql with program code only. Thank you for reply!

Answer (score 1):

In python you can clone/copy a sqlite table named "mytable" to a new table "mynewtable" using:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(file)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='mytable'")
txt=(cur.fetchone()[0])
txt=txt.replace("mytable","mynewtable")
cur.execute(txt)
cur.execute("INSERT INTO mynewtable SELECT * FROM mytable")
```

i believe this method will work similarly in other languages by: 1) getting the create mytable statement from the sqlite_master table, 2) changing only the table name, 3)execute the new create mynewtable statement and finally 4)populate the new table by inserting all data from old table